# Why is the server accepting connections after disabling the network interface?

Tags: network-interface, dhcp, ifconfig, arp

I've googled around and executed other commands (I had left here only the ones that I think are more useful). Most searches pointed me to explanations about how to shut down/up interfaces and no hints about this behaviour.

**Given:**

- A small server (Lubuntu 20.04) with two NICs (`enp3s0` and `wlp9s0`).
- A router assigning `192.168.1.78` and `.79` to `enp3s0` and `wlp9s0`, respectively, via MAC/Address reservation in the DHCP setup.
- Initially, server only connected via WiFi (`wlp9s0`), so accepting connections on `192.168.1.79` only.

**When:**

- Hours later: Eth cable (`enp3s0`) connected, `192.168.1.78` starts accepting connections.
- WiFi interface down via `sudo ifconfig wlp9s0 down`.

**Then:**

- Connection attempts to `192.168.1.79` fail (expected, OK)
- But.... many hours later: connections attempts to `192.168.1.79` start working again (?)

**More data:**

Running `arp -a` from another machine shows both IPs mapped to the same MAC addr (?):

```
d (192.168.1.78) at d3:cf:47:c8:a:a9 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.1.79) at d3:cf:47:c8:a:a9 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
```

Running `ip address` on the server confirms the WiFi link down with `192.168.1.79` still assigned to it.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> ...
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d3:cf:47:c8:a:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.78/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft 82801sec preferred_lft 82801sec
3: wlp9s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f1:bf:5c:ac:4c:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.79/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp9s0
       valid_lft 12983sec preferred_lft 12983sec
```

Why is `enp3s0` accepting traffic in both IPs now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is a not uncommon issue in Linux.  The third interface (wlp9s0) has an address.  All interfaces will ARP answer that address, and packets received on the wrong interface will be accepted for that address.

The reason it probably failed just after shutting off the interface is that the remote machine already had the wireless MAC address in its ARP table.  Once this timed out, the other address was findable.

To prevent this, remove the address outright from the down interface.
This could be using ifconfig to give it a different address or:

```
ip address del 192.168.1.79/24 dev wlp9s0
```

Comment: Thanks, David. Just to confirm: the ARP will give a positive resolution reply as long as the IP matches something linked to any local interface, regardless of the status, correct? Is this the explanation? https://serverfault.com/questions/834512/why-does-linux-answer-to-arp-on-incorrect-interfaces

Comment: Well, I will admit that I haven't heard of it doing it for DOWN interfaces before, but testing it myself, it does seem to be the case.  I think there is a sysctl value that prevents it [I don't remember the name].

Comment: Yep, it seems to be sysctls arp_ignore and arp_announce

Comment: No, I think it was arp_filter